# AWS, software slow first start

Tags: windows-server-2008, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, virtual-machines

When i launch manually a software (Autodesk 3dsmax) already installed on my AMI  instance, the first start of this software is very slow. (the next launch are ok, with a correct/normal startup time).

My instance is started from a private ebs AMI ( Windows server 2008 r2 )

I thinks that it's not specific to 3Dsmax app, but it's almost the same for all (big) software. i guess it's more relative to compiling dll etc...

Do you know a way to speed up the first launch of applications on instance started from AMI? (special AMI baking, precompiling like ngen.exe, ....)

In advance, Thanks you for your help.

Comment: Which exact type of EBS storage are you using? I've been seeing some very poor performance using GP2 recently, in a similar vein as yourself.

Comment: Hi @Chopper3 , I use also GP2 ssd, but i encounter this problem for more than 2 years now (time when i started to use EC2), so, this is not due to a temporary problem with GP2.

Comment: AMIs are stored in S3 and are streamed over as needed, this could be either the cause or contributing to it. When you look at instance statistics in CloudWatch what do you see in terms of resource usage?

Comment: Is this question is about the first time the software is started on a new instance launched from an AMI, when the volume has not been [warmed up](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ebs-initialize.html)?  If not, then what does "first launch" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AMIs are no more than collections of EBS snapshots, which are stored in S3 for increased durability and lower storage costs. Instances launched from custom AMIs need to read the initial data from S3, which is designed for a much different goal than EBS, providing better durability and object-oriented APIs, but lacking the low latency, bandwith/IO performance that EBS provides.

The only way to improve performance will be to force a straight full read of all the volume blocks by using tools like dd. After that, all of your volume blocks will be forced to be pulled from S3 to EBS, providing optimal performance for the rest of the volume life.

Newly created EBS volumes "born" in EBS, that's the reason why you can expect optimal performance from start.